# Adding custom answer in Mac Spotlight

Tags: objective-c, macos, spotlight

I saw that we have access to calculator in Spotlight! And I wonder how an application can add custom answer like calculator do!

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: no, they can't. The only thing you can write is a custom importer your application that enable spotlight to index you application data (as documents or as a database)

[Introduction to Spotlight (developer.apple.com)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MetadataIntro/MetadataIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001268)

Comment: So, the functionalities of Calculator are hard-coded into the source of Spotlight?

Comment: Yes, same for the dictionary and web searches.